# Secure Activities - no permission

Tags: android, android-activity, android-permissions

The following is found on https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/application-security-for/9781449322250/ch04.html

with the comment "To require a certain permission to start an Activity, you need to add the permission attribute to the specific Activity’s entry in AndroidManifest.xml."

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.example.testapps.test1">
 ...
    <activity android:name=".Activity1"
              android:permission="com.example.testapps.test1.permission.START_ACTIVITY1">
              <intent-filter>
                 ...
              </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  ...
</manifest>
```

What should I do if I want to prevent to start the activity? Not setting the permission seems to let the activity start without any permission...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the activity to be launched then use the following to mark it as disabled.

```
android:enabled="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do if I want to prevent to start the activity?

Remove the `<intent-filter>`. Your `<intent-filter>` is saying "I want other apps to start this activity". Activities without an `<intent-filter>` can still be started by your app, used in `PendingIntent` objects, etc.

Comment: As far as I understood the article removing the intent-filter makes it possible for all apps to start the intent?

As an example - url_launcher_plugin is accessible launching the WebViewActivity without explicit permissions:

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher">
  <application>
    <activity android:name="io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.WebViewActivity"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
      android:exported="false"/>
  </application>
</manifest>

Comment: @derChris: "
As far as I understood the article removing the intent-filter makes it possible for all apps to start the intent? " -- no. "As an example" -- not only does that activity lack an `<intent-filter>`, but it is also marked as `android:exported="false"`. `android:exported="false"` is the default value for an `<activity>` without an `<intent-filter>`, though on Android 12 and higher we should supply `android:exported` on every `<activity>`.